# traceroute gives only stars + how to fix

Tags: linux, networking, ping, traceroute

When I do:

```
  $ traceroute 8.8.8.8
```

I get in the output showing only stars, even though pinging to google.com ( 8.8.8.8) appears to be working.

1. What do I need to fix in my files/conf in order to solve this issue?
2. what I need to check?

#### Ping command output

```
    $ ping 8.8.8.8
    PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=73.4 ms
    64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=69.6 ms
```

#### traceroute command output

```
 $ traceroute 8.8.8.8
 traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
 10  * * *
 11  * * *
 12  * * *
 13  * * *
  14  * * *
 15  * * *
 16  * * *
 17  * * *
 18  * * *
 19  * * *
 20  * * *
 21  * * *
 22  * * *
 23  * * *
 24  * * *
 25  * * *
 26  * * *
 27  * * *
 28  * * *
 29  * * *
 30  * * *
```

Comment: This is usually specific to the local network you're connected to but you might want to check your firewall and/or try with a disabled local firewall.

Comment: is it posible to make a deep verification from my linux machine ? ( by linux commands )   in order to understand the problem -- please help

Comment: @Eytan, please see the updated answer. I have mentioned the configuration files that needs to be changed.

Comment: hi the configuration are the same on both machines , the machines are the same , so what next , what I need to check?

Comment: i can't even traceroute to localhost, how strange

Comment: The stars disappeared when I disabled my firewall with `iptables -F`. It is due to my firewall configuration blocking everything not going through my VPN and I just wanted to traceroute an IP address that I allowed to bypass VPN with route and iptables commands.

Answer (score 63):

I found that `traceroute -I` gave me more complete results.

```
-I, --icmp
      Use ICMP ECHO for probes
```

Comment: I get `connect: Operation not supported`

Comment: This requires root privileges.

Comment: -T to use TCP port 80 did it for me. eg `traceroute -T google.com`

Answer (score 30):

The asterisks you're seeing are servers that your packets are being routed through whom are timing out (5.0+ seconds) and so `traceroute` defaults to printing the *.

**NOTE**: There's even a warning about this in the `traceroute` man page.

*excerpt*

> In the modern network environment the traditional traceroute methods
>   can not be always applicable, because of widespread use of firewalls.
>   Such firewalls filter the "unlikely" UDP ports, or even ICMP echoes.
>   To solve this, some additional tracerouting methods are implemented
>   (including tcp), see LIST OF AVAILABLE METHODS below. Such methods try
>   to use particular protocol and source/destination port, in order to
>   bypass firewalls (to be seen by firewalls just as a start of allowed
>   type of a network session).

Most firewalls block traffic outbound on ports other than TCP/80 which is the default IP port for web traffic. `traceroute` in Linux default use `UDP`, ping use `ICMP`, so as your output, it seems that `ICMP` packets are allowed in your firewall whereas `UDP` packets are blocked by the firewall.

You can see responses to my question titled: [traceroute and ping from school network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125317/traceroute-and-ping-from-school-network).

#### EDIT #1

As per the comments, if this is working in another RHEL machine and not working in this RHEL machine, I would suggest doing the below steps.

From the working RHEL machine (machine A), copy the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file. In the faulty RHEL machine (machine B), copy the original `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file to something like `/etc/sysconfig/iptables.original`.

```
$ cp /etc/sysconfig/iptables /etc/sysconfig/iptables.original
```

This step is just to ensure that if something goes wrong with our setting, we can revert back to the original. Now, copy the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` from the machine A to machine B.

Comment: so the stars are a bad sign? - they indicate about problem ?

Comment: but if they block by the Firewall so I have problem -

Comment: but how to know if the problem in my linux machine / or maybe the problem is some external isshue?

Comment: this machine is in the network I have some other machine but the output on the other machine is diff ( not all stars )

Comment: did you mean about the linux firewall ? or other firewall ?

Comment: so how you explain if some machine are ok and some othe rmachine in the smae network have bad results ( stars )

Comment: no all machines are red-hat exepet one unbuntu machine ( all them are VM machine )  , not understand why some of them are ok and some of them get bad results from traceroute

Comment: hi again the file iptables is the same on both machine ( the good one have the same file as the faulty one )

Comment: I believe both these machines might be forwarding the packets to some other machine and so in that machine it is possible that the packets from machine B is blocked. I suggest you to open another question with the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` rules in the question which will help people debug the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Either the machine you are running the tests from or your local gateway (router) is blocking UDP or ICMP. Make sure these are allowed in your firewall / NAT rule configuration.

Comment: A bit more detail on how to do that would be helpful.

Comment: please advice about the commands that need to run on my linux machine in order to check the firewall / NAT as you explained

Comment: ICMP per se is not being entirely   blocked as the OP is doing pings.